# Core Data Makes attribute NULL when switching views

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I have four views.

View 1, shows a table view with an add button. (Add button not visible, it is above screen shot bounds)

[image: View 1]

View 2 ( presented when add button is pressed) allows the user to input data about the table view cell they would like to add. 
Once the `save` button is pressed, the new cell is added to the view.

[image: view 2]

View 3 If the user would like to edit a cell, they just tap the cell. This view Just allows the user to edit the cell that is already in the table.

[image: view 3]

But when i simply put view 4 in between view 1 (the table view) and 3 (the cell editor view), the attributes/labels show `null` where the user input is supposed to be shown. But when i remove view 4 from in between view 1 and 3, the app works perfect again. Any reasons?

[image: view 4]

I am simply switching views via:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

View3 * three = (View3 *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view3VC"];

View4 * four = (View4 *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view4VC"];

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

three.managedObjectContext = self.context;

MyEntityClass *entity = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

three.3entity = entity;

[self presentViewController:four animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: u didn't mention what's view4 for

Comment: This view isnt exactly a finished product per say. I would just like to fix the problem because i will need to, eventually, add a fourth view into the app! so, i just threw a button on the view to demonstrate the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing but I think I would try to help you.

In your code:

```
MyEntityClass *entity = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
three.3entity = entity;
```

You said it works when you call view3, I guess it is because you've assign the entity to the view3.

But if you present view4 like this, you didn't assign anything to it between.

```
View4 * four = (View4 *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view4VC"];
```

AND

```
[self presentViewController:four animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now view4 is a totally fresh and empty view controller. It's not strange that it shows `null` in your labels.

Try fix it in the way exactly as view3.